# Apache Commons Compress Cannot Resolve Class SeekableInMemoryByteChannel Prior to Android N

Tags: java, android, apache-commons-compress

Whenever I try to use the `SeekableInMemoryByteChannel` class from the Apache commons-compress package the application crashes with a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.compress.utils.SeekableInMemoryByteChannel` exception.

The particularly interesting part of this, for me at least, is that the issue does not occur on devices running Android 7+, but does on all other versions that I have tested. To be more specific I have observed that this issue occurs on Android 6.0.1, 6.0, 5.1.1 but **does not occur** on Android 7.0 or 7.1.1. Each of these devices comes from a different vendor.

So I'm facing a severe case of ghost class. At first I thought that this may have been related to the fact that my app was using MultiDex, or that the build process was incorrectly configured. But the same happens on a completely new project that does not have these features. I've tried to use different classes from the same package and they are resolved successfully. I added the package to ProGuard but no luck.

This is the code that replicates the issue:

```
package lt.kaz.compresstest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZArchiveEntry;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry;
import org.apache.commons.compress.utils.SeekableInMemoryByteChannel;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ZipArchiveEntry zipEntry = new ZipArchiveEntry("hello");
        zipEntry.setSize(600);

        SevenZArchiveEntry sevenZipEntry = new SevenZArchiveEntry();
        sevenZipEntry.setName("sevenZip");

        try {
            MainActivity.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("org.apache.commons.compress.utils.ChecksumCalculatingInputStream");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SeekableInMemoryByteChannel channel = new SeekableInMemoryByteChannel(new byte[]{5, 10, 15, 10});
        // App never gets here prior to Android N
        Log.d("lt.kaz", channel.toString());
    }
}
```

... and the gradle file ...

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'lt.kaz.compresstest'
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.14'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

... and ProGuard ...

```
-keep public class org.apache.commons.compress
```

Any help would be really appreciated. What could be the reason for such behaviour? How can it be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the `SeekableByteChannel` interface form the `java.nio.channels` package is [only available](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/SeekableByteChannel.html) from Android API level 24 (hence android N).

My final solution, since my original intent was to use the `SevenZFile` class, was to downgrade commons-compress to version 1.12, since the implementation there doesn't use the the `SeekableByteChannel` class.